# why does google dataproc does not pull coreNLP jars although they are included in POM file?

Tags: java, maven, stanford-nlp, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

My application is a java maven project that uses Spark. Here's the section in my pom that adds stanford coreNLP dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <classifier>models</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP
```

there are other dependencies, e.g. Spark, and dataproc pulls them fine. Now I added coreNLP and it works fine on my laptop, but fails in google dataproc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark classes are "provided" in the Dataproc environment because they're considered part of the base distribution, alongside other Hadoop-related packages like [hadoop-client](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client). Other libraries which aren't part of the base distribution should be packaged as part of your "fatjar" using the [Maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html).

Generally this is a best practice guideline because the "provided" environment should be as un-opinionated as possible about version dependencies, and this way you can bring your own version of corenlp as necessary without worrying about version collisions on the Dataproc environment, or even to use your own forked version of the corenlp libraries.